# Centralizar imagem na barra do menu nav

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Como faço para centralizar uma imagem na barra de Menu? Quando falo em centralizar, me refiro não a imagem no meio da barra, mas em qualquer posição que ela esteja, que tenha as mesmas "medidas" para o top e para o bottom. Como defino isso em meu `css`? Abaixo o código do meu menu. Gostaria que a imagem estivesse antes do "Nome da Minha Empresa" e não depois, como está.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img src="~/Images/Logomarca_mini.jpg" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Nome da Minha Empresa", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Defina os elementos no mesmo nível que a imagem com `display: inline-block` e line-height com o mesmo tamanho do container

http://jsfiddle.net/4hr29t6w/2/

para o button ficar certo, no exemplo defina um height e margens de acordo com o tamanho do container

Answer (score 1):

Aqui resolveu:

```
.....
</button>

  <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="~/Images/Logomarca_mini.jpg">
     </a>
  </div>
.....
```